# Print BIG Words on Console - using python, bit by bit

Tags: python

I need to write a BIG word on a console, Each character of word should actually comprise of parts, and each part will reveal slowly over the screen, pretty much like this attached picture [image: Gradual]

Is there a python library that can do this for me, I have searched enough but couldn't find any so far

Comment: or should I give this a try http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php

Comment: have you tried using `termcolor` module?

Comment: Do you want to write this as ASCII art? (on the console) or using graphics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print ASCII-art words, you should look at the pyfiglet library

https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet

To get the effect that you want, a simple script could be:

```
import os
import time 

from pyfiglet import Figlet

f = Figlet(font='slant')
word = 'HELLO'
curr_word = ''
for char in word:
    os.system('reset') #assuming the platform is linux, clears the screen
    curr_word += char;
    print f.renderText(curr_word)
    time.sleep(1)
```

(note: I haven't tested the script, but the concept should be correct)

Answer (score 11):

Another ASCII art python package:

https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/art

> ART is a Python lib for text converting to ASCII art fancy. ;-)

```
>>> tprint("art") # print ASCII text (default font) 
              _   
  __ _  _ __ | |_ 
 / _` || '__|| __|
| (_| || |   | |_ 
 \__,_||_|    \__|
```

[image]